# How do I disable cache for a certain page?

Tags: php, plugin-development, javascript, html, cache

Wordpress beginner here with a probably easy problem, yet I don't know how to do it. I want to disable caching on certain pages of my site.

I best describe what I do:

- I have written a plugin in php
- the php files (among other things) create a html that I insert via shortcode into a WP page
- this html does use some javascript files - a leaflet map to be precise
- on my site, the users can create such leaflet maps (on one page) and show them to the world (on another page)
- Now when the user changes something on the authoring page, it is (most of the time) not shown on the audience page unless the user clears the cache.

I tried adding a random key to the .js file like this `<script src="test.js?random=<?php echo uniqid(); ?>"></script>` but it does not work.

I think I need to use some these hooks I keep hearing about, but I have no clue how.

If you want to see it in action, you can take a look at an [audience page here](https://fictionalmaps.com/audience-map/?creator=13&map=Summerfrostsetting) or go ahead, [make an account](https://fictionalmaps.com/register/) and test see the whole workflow.

Comment: It depends on what plugin you're using to cache the pages to begin with. Check its documentation.

Comment: I'm not using any caching plugins at all